# SQL - Only choose unique names by max date?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a table called Locations that looks like this

```
Name       Date
Location A 01/01/2014
Location A 12/12/2013
Location B 01/01/2014
Location C 01/01/2014
Location D 01/01/2014
Location D 12/12/2013
Location E 12/12/2013
```

I want to return only the Names where the date is MAX(Date) i.e. 01/01/2014 and where there is only 1 row for this Name and the date is MAX(Date)

To explain further I would like to return

```
Name       Date
Location B 01/01/2014
Location C 01/01/2014
```

I have tried a few queries like a HAVING statement but cannot seem to get the desired result

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
declare @t table (Name varchar(49), [Date] date)
insert into @t(Name,[Date]) values
('Location A','20140101'),
('Location A','20131212'),
('Location B','20140101'),
('Location C','20140101'),
('Location D','20140101'),
('Location D','20131212'),
('Location E','20131212')

select Name,MAX(Date)
from @t
group by Name
having MIN(Date) = (select MAX(Date) from @t)
```

It doesn't matter much which aggregate you use here:

```
select Name,MAX(Date)
```

provided the reference to `Date` is in an aggregate.

Result:

```
Name                                              
------------------------------------------------- ----------
Location B                                        2014-01-01
Location C                                        2014-01-01
```

The logic is - if the *earliest* date for a particular `Name` is also the *latest* date for the whole table, then logically there's only one entry for this `Name` and it is for the latest date in the table.

(This is based on the assumption that each location can only have one entry per day)

Comment: This would return a location if it had two rows with the same date. Not clear that this is possible, but would include a `and COUNT(1) = 1` in the `HAVING` for completeness.

Comment: I didnt think of using MIN(ImportDate), good move! Thanks worked well

Comment: @JonEgerton - I was considering whether to add that as an explicit assumption on my part

Answer (score 1):

We can first check the names which are not repeating using `GROUP BY` and `COUNT` in inner query and then `inner join` this one with original table over which we group by name and date to calculate max value dates and corresponding name

```
SELECT t.Name, MAX(Date) From table INNER JOIN 
(SELECT DISTINCT Name from table group by Name having count(Name)=1) t 
ON t.name=table.name
GROUP BY Date,t.Name
```

Comment: This also worked, the first option was slightly easier so went with that but thanks for the input here!

Comment: @DtotheG Thank you for confirming! +1 to your question! :)

Answer (score 0):

Easy to follow logic version:

```
select name,date = max(date)
from Locations
group by name
having max(date) = (select max(date) from Locations)
and count(1) = 1
```

[SQL Fiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/98226/10)

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @t table (Name varchar(49), [Date] date)
insert into @t(Name,[Date]) values
('Location A','20140101'),
('Location A','20131212'),
('Location B','20140101'),
('Location C','20140101'),
('Location D','20140101'),
('Location D','20131212'),
('Location E','20131212')

select Name, [Date] from
(
select Name,[Date], 
maxdate =  max([Date]) over ( ),
Cnt =  count(*) over ( PARTITION by Name )
from @t
) Res
where [Date] = maxdate
and cnt = 1
```